# Проблема с консольным приложением Qt

Tags: c++, qt, консоль

Не выплняются команды C++ Qt.
Выводится только первый cout и все, хотя должна выводится ещё и переменная.
PS: С любым командами после первого cout так-же.

.pro

```
 TEMPLATE = app
    TARGET = HeuralNetwork

    QT -= gui
    QT += core

    CONFIG += console
    CONFIG -= app_bundle

    SOURCES += \
            main.cpp
```

.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QtGui/QImage>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
    QTextStream cin(stdin);
    QTextStream cout(stdout);

    cout << QString("Write image ref:") << endl;
    QString imageRef;
    cin >> imageRef;
    //QImage image("D:/Qt Sources/NeuralNetwork/Images/1_1.png");
    cout << imageRef;

    return app.exec();
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, текст проблемы в вопрос

Comment: а почему не использовать классические cout/cin? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26192013/qtextstream-stdin-readline-not-pausing-for-input

Comment: Они не работают с QString

Comment: А флашить тут не надо?

Comment: была как-то проблема с тем, что в консоль выводилось выборочно и не всегда одно и то же. с чем связана, так и не понял, решил костылем - заменил `cout` на `qDebug()`

Comment: после 'cout' просто ставте 'endl;' или 'cout.flush()' если хотите быстро

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я немного опоздал, но пользователь с ником `@Kirill Pukhov` сказал что `cout` и `cin` не работает с данным типом данных, возможно вам придется перегрузить оператор `<<` https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/1z2f6c2k.aspx

Вот пример

```
#include <iostream>  
using namespace std;  

class Point  
{  
    int x, y; 
public:  
    Point(int x, int y)  
    {  
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
    }  
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Point& p);  
};  

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Point& p)  
{  
    os << "x: " << p.x << "; y: " << p.y;
    return os;
}  

int main()  
{  
    Point p(5, 6);  
    cout << p << endl;  
}
```

Добавлю что выводить `QString` в консоль не лучшая идея, ведь `QString` использует кодировку UTF-8, в консоли windows консолью желательно использовать wchar

Comment: Думаю, `Kirill Pukhov` оставил комментарий `KoVadim`, у автора вопроса cin/cout не сишные, а qt-шные, которые умеют с QString работать: http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qtextstream.html#operator-lt-lt-12

Comment: упс, простите >_<

Comment: Да ладно вам... бывает :)